# How to Prepopulate TO field while sending email in activity history Lightning Experience

Tags: email, lightning-experience

How to Prepopulate To field before send an email in Activity History

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, You can do it. Go to the action you have created and go to predefined field values section.

[image]

Click on new and select **to** field in the field name then specify the field values for **to** field.

[image]

Read more about it here:- [Set Predefined Field Values for Quick Action Fields](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=predefined_field_values.htm&type=5)